# Grammar Writing Tools

Tags: grammar, parsing, ebnf

I am trying to write a grammar in EBNF (barring a really good reason, it has to be EBNF) and am looking for a couple of utilities for it - if there's a GUI interface that can make one, that would be great, but the thing I'm looking for most is something that can check the grammar, for instance to see if it is LALR(*n*), and if so, what the value of *n* is. Do such utilities exist? Are there any other useful grammar-writing tools I should know about (I'm not looking for parser generators).

Comment: In case someone else was wondering: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBNF

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taking Steven Dee's suggestion one step further, you might want to check out [ANTLRWorks](http://www.antlr.org/works/index.html), which is an interactive GUI development tool for ANTLR grammars.

Answer (score 9):

Use **TinyPG**! Its an amazing all-in-one **compiler compiler** with a lightweight GUI, where you build your parser with **RegEx**, **EBNF**, and write **C#/VB** code to do something with the **parse tree**!

Here's a short and informative summary that I did earlier, which also links you to the downloads.

---

***My understandings of TinyPG:***

[TinyPG](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/TinyPG.aspx) allows you to write & develop:

- Define **Terminals** using [**Regular Expressions**.](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/regextutorial.aspx)
- Define **Non-terminals** and parser rules in [**Extended BNF** meta-syntax.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBNF)
- Write **Compiler** code in **C# or VB**, within TinyPG.

It has an in-built IDE, Windows Only *(created in C#.NET, open source)*.

It allows you to try out & preview **Regular Expressions** using the inbuilt **RegEx tool.** RegEx syntax is supported in .NET which means that even your **outputted parser code** uses .NET's Regular Expressions.

You write EBNF to describe the **language of your choice** *(Here are some freely available [BNF Grammers that describe modern programming languages](http://www.devincook.com/GOLDParser/grammars/index.htm) (C, Java, JavaScript, C#, VB.NET, SQL-89)*

Using TinyPG, your **RegEx** along with your **EBNF** outputs a **parse-tree** [*(see this diagram)*](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/a/a9/Parser_Flow.gif).

Now what do you do with the parse-tree? You write **C#/VB code** *(within TinyPG, per BNF grammer rule)* for your **Compiler/Interpreter/Translator.** *(inside TinyPG, open the "simple expression2.tpg" file within the provided Samples to see a demo of a **calculator** 'compiler')*

TinyPG allows you to **Compile and Test** your **tokenizer+parser+complier**, within the TinyPG IDE, and it finally outputs the **parser source code** in C#.NET or VB.NET *(your choice)*, with **ready-to-use** classes.

An excellent **All-in-one Compiler Compiler** for the masses. Enjoy!

*PS: Correct me if I'm wrong on any of this.*

Answer (score 1):

To check whether a grammar allows a certain parser algorithm, just put it into the parser generator. In case of LALR(1), pass the grammar to YACC to see whether it detects conflicts.

Answer (score 1):

[CoCo/R](http://www.ssw.uni-linz.ac.at/Coco/) C# is missing from the list. It is simple to use, very versatile and especially useful has code generators for a great variety of languages

Coco/R for C#, Java, C++, F#, VB.Net, Oberon, other languages

[1] http://www.ssw.uni-linz.ac.at/Coco/

Answer (score 0):

[ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/) is a GUI parser generator in Java that has extensive capabilities for grammar analysis and factoring. Check the FAQ; it might support what you're looking for.