# How to write a parser for a configuration file in python

Tags: python, parsing

I have a non-standard configuration file, for which I want to write a python parser.

What is the best approach to writing a parser from scratch?

Example of a configuration file:

```
// Comment 
conf OPTION_NAME {
     (
       ( option1:"string"
         option2:"14"
       )
     )
}


// Comment2 
conf OPTION_NAME2 {
     (
       ( option1:"string2"
         option2:"15"
       )
     )
}
```

Comment: Is the format of the configuration file under your control?

Comment: Unfortunately, no , it's a legacy file, not under my control. But this is a good exercise for any non-standard conf file/code.

Comment: There's not enough information here. What is the grammar of this language?

Comment: Write a BNF grammar first, (if you can't change the config so you can). Perhaps this SO post might help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/264262/grammar-writing-tools

Comment: I would say that this really depends on how flexible your format is. For instance, I don't see the point of the double nesting inside your options unless it allows for constructions you didn't tell us of.

Comment: I've used [`PyParsing`](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/) the few times I've had to write a parser in Python. The first thing you should do is write down the grammar of your language.

Answer (score 2):

I would personally use PLY: http://www.dabeaz.com/ply/

Here's a simple example:

http://www.dabeaz.com/ply/example.html

Here's an example from one of my own projects:

https://github.com/fogleman/FeedNotifier/blob/master/filters.py

Alternatively, since the files look very simple, I might just use a handmade Finite State Machine to do the parsing.